# Cascade filter realization equivalence?

Tags: filters, transfer-function, control-systems

Given

$$H(z) = \frac{11 +4.6z^{-1} -26z^{-2}-3.75z^{-3}}{1-z^{-1}-8.75z^{-2}}$$

I'd like to know whether this realization: 
[image: Direct form realization]
Is equivalent to this one? 
[image: Canonic realization]

In short, is the direct form realization equivalent to the canonic one?

Comment: I don't see the difference. Both are the same and both are canonic.

Answer (score 1):

As MattL already mentioned, they are the same block diagrams as **Direct Form II (canonical)** implementation of a third order (on the FIR side) LCCDE.

However, the adders in the first block diagram are two input adders, while the the ones in the second block diagram are multiple input adders. Theoretically there is no difference.

In a popular DSP text, only the former block diagram is displayed, with sum (sigma) symbol replaced with a + sign.